# Continuous partial derivatives at $x_0$ and differentiability around $x_0$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Consider function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose

> 1) At ${\bf x}_0$, $f({\bf x})$ has partial derivatives ${\bf J}({\bf x}_0)$.
>
> 2) ${\bf J}({\bf x})$ is continuous at ${\bf x}_0$.

I know that $f({\bf x})$ [is differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007709/proof-that-continuous-partial-derivatives-implies-differentiability) at ${\bf x}_0$.

> **Question**: Is there a neighborhood of ${\bf x}_0$ on which $f({\bf x})$ is differentiable?

I know $f({\bf x})$ has partial derivatives on a neighborhood of ${\bf x}_0$, however this [does not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87688/does-existence-of-partial-derivatives-implies-continuity-at-a-point-x-0-y-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) [necessarily imply](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934503/suppose-all-partial-derivatives-of-f-exist-at-x-0-is-f-continuous-at-x-0?rq=1) that $f({\bf x})$ is differentiable there.